# drop down opens up on every Item I map through How can I make open up only on the one I clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a page that's mapping through Items and displaying there information I have a drop down that gives an option to edit and delete the item. the problem is when I click the drop down on one items card it opens up on all the items I am mapping threw instead of just that Item I clicked. the Item opens by setting isActive3 to true

```
  optionsClicked = () => {
    this.setState({ isActive3: !this.state.isActive3 })
   };


 <div className="updateInfo">
    <div className="timenOptions"> 
      <div className="time">{moment(content.dateCreated).calendar()}</div>
      <div className= {this.state.isActive3 ? "optionsContainer active" : "optionsContainer"} onClick={this.optionsClicked} > 
        <div className="options"> ...</div>  
        <div className="optionsDropdown">
            <ul className="optionsList">
             <div className="edit"> Edit</div>
             <div className= "delete" onClick={this.removeItem}>Delete</div>
            </ul>
        </div>
       </div>     
    </div>
    <p>{content.content}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem with your code** - Your `state` currently holds only one property `isActive3` that controls active state for all the rows.

**Solution** - The solution is to have mapping between some property which is unique to each row and active state in your State object.

Example State:

```
[
 {YourUniqueId : 1, isActive3: false},
 {YourUniqueId : 2, isActive3: true},
 {YourUniqueId : 3, isActive3: false}
]
```

Your onClick call should then change to

```
() => this.optionsClicked(currentRowUniqueId)
```

Your `optionsClicked` function should then loop through all the items and set only current item's `isActive3` to `true` and remaining all `isActive3`s to `false`.

Comment: all the items do have an Id because I am pulling them from a data base but it seems a bit tedious to loop through all the items which could be 1000 just to activate a drop down for one particular item.  I was thinking about maybe adding a ref then onclick the ref could be put into state and trigger the active class for that particular item and I could get rid of isActive3 all together?

Comment: Yeah, you could. But you will still be looping through the state though. Other alternative is to have a child component and invoke child component's function. That might probably an overkill. What I posted as an answer is one solution that will work and probably makes most sense in this scenario.